# iOS Tetsflight manual distribution to testers groups

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I'm using TestFlight for distribution of my app for 2 groups of internal testers. When I upload the build through Xcode and later it's shown in the app store connect, the invitations are already sent. I would like to change the automatic distribution to manual. The objective is to manual select on group of testers first and then add others later. Also to give me a chance to write the test details in the build before sending the invitations. Is this possible? I don't see the any option to change the type of distribution to manual when I upload the build to the app store connect. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5):

For all external testing groups, you will need to provide a build manually each time

For internal groups you have the option for `Automatic` or `Manual` distribution via the `Enable automatic distribution` checkbox. You can select this option when you create the new internal group

[image: app store connect new internal group]

**Note:** This value cannot be changed after the group has been created.

Thankfully it is really easy to create new groups and add testers. Removing testers will not remove them from testflight, and adding them to a new group will not trigger a new email invitation (unless they have not accepted the original invite)

Comment: So there is no way to provide the new builds to  external testers automatically?

Comment: No there is not, you'd have to release those manually. Its safer that way, even though it is annoying

Answer (score 2):

Builds are released automatically to groups under the "Internal Testing" section. Builds have to be released manually to the groups under "External Testing"

Anyone you don't want to access it immediately, simply move them to an External group. Note that there is a delay in external users getting access, as apps have to go through a smaller review process. It can take a few hours for the builds to go out (usually)

Comment: I see. I thought there was a way I could add those groups manually by uploaded build for internal testers. Thanks.